# MongoDB LIKE vs. Mysql LIKE

Tags: mysql, mongodb, search, sql-like

I am moving some parts of a site from mysql to mongodb, and one part that will use mongodb is search. There I have one problem, if I make this query in mysql

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE a1 LIKE '%test%' OR a2 LIKE '%test%'
```

I will get over 10k results. That's ok.

If I do this query in mongo

```
$mongo->find(
    array(
        '$or' => array(
            array('a1' => new MongoRegex('/test/')),
            array('a2' => new MongoRegex('/test/'))
        )
    )
)->count();
```

I will get around 2k results, 5x fewer. How is that happening?

The data in each db is the same.

Comment: Does your SQL `table` and MongoDB collection have the same number of records in total?

Comment: likei said, its same DB , they are totaly same, 65k records both have

Comment: Please note that this will not use the index efficiently, if you have one on a1/2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL's [LIKE is case-insensitive](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) by default:

> The following two statements illustrate that string comparisons are not case sensitive unless one of the operands is a binary string:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT 'abc' LIKE 'ABC';
>    -> 1
> ```

But MongoDB's regex searches will be case-sensitive by default because JavaScript's regexes are case sensitive.

Try using a case-insensitive regex. I'm not familiar with MongoRegex's syntax but [the fine manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoregex.php) says that the usual `/i` modifier should work:

```
new MongoRegex('/test/i')
```

The case issue is consistent with getting a lot more matches in MySQL (~10k) than MongoDB (~2k).

Comment: I add "i" for insensitive and i only double results, but still alot less then mysql, 36 times less results

Comment: @Squirll: What are some things that MySQL finds that MongoDB doesn't or vice versa?

Comment: let say "free tickets"  or just "tickets" there is plany articals in db with that but mongo found just few

Comment: What does one that MongoDB didn't find look like? You need to be more specific about what's being missed.

Comment: Example word Airplain.. we have articles with " Free Airplain Tickets" and mongo will not find that article, and mysql will find or will find small numer of articals who contains word Airplain

Comment: Have you tried `db.articles.find({text: /airplain/i})` right from the MongoDB shell? You'd have to use the right collection and field names of course. And are you sure that your data has ASCII "Airplain" rather than some Unicode stuff that just looks the same?

Comment: Ofcourse i try in shell, and i get same number of results, and im sure that is ASCII stuff.